# ayuda codificaion cenit polar en c

Tags: c, string, lista, array, codeblocks

hice un programa en codeblocks el cual deberia codificar en cenit polar y si bien identifica los caracteres y los intercambia genera un problema con los caracteres que no se intercambian transformándolos en caracteres completamente distintos

```
    void f()
    {
        int i,p;
        char n[30],c[30];

        char g[]="cenit";
        char k[]="polar";

        printf("cenit\n");
        fgets(n,30,stdin);
        printf("%s",n);

        for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            for(p=0;p<6;p++)
            {
                if(n[i]==g[p])
                {
                    c[i]=k[p];
                }

                if(n[i]==k[p])
                {
                    c[i]=g[p];
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%s\n",c);
    }
```

Comment: Podrías proporcionar un ejemplo de entrada y cuál es la salida que genera?

Comment: Si tu pregunta fué resuelta te recomiendo señales la respuesta que creas resolvió tu pregunta. Para mas información consulta [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Si tu código está arrojando códigos extraños es porque el arreglo que utilizas coo salida (`c[30]`) no lo estás inicializando. Es por ello que se queda con valores "basura". Para inicializar dicho arreglo tienes algunas alternativas. La mas común será emplear un ciclo `for` como el siguiente:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++)
{
    c[i] = '\0';
}
```

Esto hará que el arreglo quede inicializado con caracteres de terminación de cadena.

Recordemos que en C, el fin de una cadena se identifica a través del caractér de terminación de cadena `'\0'`. Por ejemplo, la cadena que tienes definida en la siguiente línea:

```
char g[]="cenit"
```

Estará compuesta por los caracteres:

```
{'c', 'e', 'n', 'i', 't', '\0'}
```

Es por eso que su tamaño es **6**

Lo demás de tu lógica se ve bien aunque por claridad usaría un **else-if**

```
            if(n[i]==g[p])
            {
                c[i]=k[p];
            }

            else if(n[i]==k[p])
            {
                c[i]=g[p];
            }
```

Comment: también valdría `int c[30] = { '\0' };`... no es necesario currarse un bucle para estas inicializaciones